# How can I display two separate data sets on a map in tableau?

Tags: dictionary, geocoding, tableau-api

I have geo-coded data that allows me to plot a couple of pipelines on a map.  I have a second set of data that has geo-coded data for power plants.  I would like to plot the pipelines as line segments and power plants as shapes.  I know how to do each of the operations individually; but cannot get them to display the way I want on the same map.  Can somebody tell me how I can create two layers of data on the same map in tableau?  Is there a better program I should be using to do this?
Much appreciated.

Comment: You need to concatenate those two tables. Tableau won't do it for you directly, unless those tables are in db that Tableau allows you to do a custom SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two data sets open parallely. Once you open one dataset, Tableau will divide the columns in dimensions and measures. After that you can go to Data>Connect to data, to open another data set on top of it. You can then plot variables from both of them on the same map. Hope this helps.